How to get double tap gesture touch location details in ios15
All,
I would like to get double tap gesture tapped location coordinates to zoom tapped area.
Using below code for single tap,
onTapGesture { location in print("Tapped at \(location)")

I need same location with double tap also in ios 15.
Thank you for support and answer will much helped.

That is not possible without UIKit. Since you are zooming in a view, it might be better to do the whole view in UIKit.

I think the only way back then was with DragGesture, DragGesture with a zero distance is a tap. maybe if you combine tap gestures and drag gestures

How can we combile? Please give some more details

Simultaneous gesture, idk if it will work for sure, just an idea.

This extension adds a custom double-tap gesture recognizer to a SwiftUI view, with options to customize the sensitivity and the location reporting of the double-tap.
Parameters:
sensitivity: A Double that defines the maximum time interval (in seconds) between two taps to be recognized as a double-tap. By default, it is set to 0.25 seconds.
coordinateSpace: A CoordinateSpace value that determines the space in which the location of the double-tap will be reported. The default is .local, meaning the location is reported relative to the view’s local coordinate system.
location: A closure that takes a CGPoint and is called when the double-tap occurs, providing the exact location of the tap.
Functionality: The function applies a modifier (OnDoubleTapGestureViewModifier) to the view, which handles the double-tap gesture detection, applying the specified sensitivity and reporting the tap's location using the provided closure.
Returns: A modified view with the double-tap gesture recognizer applied, which will respond to double-tap gestures and call the location closure with the coordinates of the tap.
Requirements: Requires iOS 14.0 or later, or macOS 11.0 or later.

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var doubleTapLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .overlay(Text(describingDoubleTapLocation(value: doubleTapLocation)).bold())
            .onDoubleTapGesture { location in
                doubleTapLocation = location
                print("Double Tap! Location:" + String(describing: location))
            }
    }
    
    private func describingDoubleTapLocation(value: CGPoint?) -> String {
        if let unwrappedValue: CGPoint = value {
            return "Location: (" + formater(unwrappedValue.x) + ", " + formater(unwrappedValue.y) + ")"
        }
        else {
            return "Double tap me!"
        }
    }
    
    private func formater(_ value: CGFloat) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", value)
    }
    
}


struct OnDoubleTapGestureViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    init(sensitivity: Double = 0.25, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .local, doubleTapLocation: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void) {
        self.sensitivity = sensitivity
        self.coordinateSpace = coordinateSpace
        self.doubleTapLocation = doubleTapLocation
    }
    
    var sensitivity: Double
    var coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
    var doubleTapLocation: (CGPoint) -> Void
    
    @State private var resetTimer: Timer? = nil
    @State private var doubleTapCount: Int8 = 0
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: .zero, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace)
            .onChanged { gestureValue in
                
                if (gestureValue.translation == .zero) {
                    
                    doubleTapCount += 1
                    
                    if (doubleTapCount == 2) {
                        resetTimer?.invalidate()
                        doubleTapCount = 0
                        doubleTapLocation(gestureValue.startLocation)
                    }
                    else {
                        resetTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: sensitivity, repeats: false) {  _ in
                            doubleTapCount = 0
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .onEnded { gestureValue in
                
                if (gestureValue.translation == .zero) {
                    if (doubleTapCount >= 2) {
                        resetTimer?.invalidate()
                        doubleTapCount = 0
                    }
                }
                
            }
    }
}


extension View {
    
    /// Adds a double-tap gesture recognizer to a view with customizable sensitivity and reports the location of the double-tap.
    ///
    /// - Requires: iOS 14.0 or later, macOS 11.0 or later.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - sensitivity: A `Double` value representing the maximum time interval (in seconds) between two taps to register as a double-tap. Default is `0.25`.
    ///   - coordinateSpace: The coordinate space in which the double-tap location should be reported. Default is `.local`.
    ///   - location: A closure that receives the `CGPoint` where the double-tap occurred.
    /// - Returns: A modified view with the double-tap gesture applied.
    func onDoubleTapGesture(sensitivity: Double = 0.25, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .local, location: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(OnDoubleTapGestureViewModifier(sensitivity: sensitivity, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace, doubleTapLocation: location))
    }
    
}

